# TodoMVC app using Backbone.js and SQL Server instead of backbone-localstorage.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-2, todomvc

I am learning backbone.js, I have gone through these series of tutorials before : [Link1](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-1/), [Link2](http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/01/backbone-js-part-1/)

Now I am going through [TodoMVC using Backbone.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/) and you can see the code here.

- [Html Code](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/) - View Source
- [js/models/todo.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/models/todo.js)
- [js/collections/todos.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/collections/todos.js)
- [js/views/todos.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/todos.js)
- [js/views/app.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app.js)
- [js/routers/router.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/routers/router.js)
- [js/app.js](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/app.js)

**What I want to do**

As you can see in the [example](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/), the example uses **backbone-localstorage.js**, now instead of this I want to implement the same thing using ASP.NET MVC, where the values will be stored in a SQL Server database.

I am really confused on how to start about on this, can anyone please guide me on how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look at ServiceStack. They also have a TODO app [example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples).
ServiceStack and Backbone.js go well together. Once you're on the server, storing data wherever you like, shouldn't be a problem.
The example is included in this Nuget package

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.Mvc
```